# Matlab - No output is returned

Tags: matlab, output

I have the following function, provided that the code for `pdist2` is [here](http://code.google.com/p/cs250b-projects/source/browse/trunk/Project3/toolbox/classify/pdist2.m?spec=svn81&r=81).

```
function m = pixel_minimize_distance(x,y)

maximum = (sum(sum(pdist2(x,y))));
[r c] = size(y);
initialValue = y(1,1);
for i=1:r
    for j=1:c
        o = y(i,j);
        y(i,j) = 0;
        sum2 = (sum(sum(pdist2(x,y))));


        if sum2 >= maximum
            if o ~= 0
                maximum = sum2;
                m = o;
            end
        maximum = maximum;
        m = initialValue;
        end
        y(i,j)=o;
    end
    end
end
```

Now, when I try to run the function, I don't get an output as shown below:

```
>> A=[0 0 0; 0 0 0];
>> B=[1 1 1; 1 1 1];
>> pixel_minimize_distance(A,B)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not a good practice [to use `i` and `j` as variables in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Answer (score 2):

don't call the variable `maximum` as it is a Matlab function (Simulink's, actually).

Still, do you know that

```
maximum=maximum
```

is not doing nothing?

alsodo you know that the line

```
if sum2 >= maximum
```

is not doing nothing neither? `sum2` is never being updated, well beter say, it is several times being updated WITH THE SAME VALUE. check your code, it has little sense rigth now.

EDIT: maybe with some different matrixes will do something.... but with the ones you provide not.

Answer (score 1):

Since you replace the (i,j) element of **y** with 0 after reading it here:

`o = y(i,j);
 y(i,j) = 0;`

and since all entries of **y** are positive in your test case, the condition:

`if sum2 >= maximum`

never evaluates to **true**. Consecutively, the output variable **m** gets never initialized hence the function returns nothing.

Try to initialize **m** at the start of your function to empty or some other default value that would make sense.